# How do I find the OU a computer account is in using vb.net framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, active-directory

I've spent a couple of days pulling my hair out with various snippets of code and methods so I'm going to start afresh and make this an open question as I'm not experienced enough with vb to have a preference how I accomplish the task (although the simpler and more efficient the better, obviously).

I am running my vb.net framework 3.5 application on a workstation in a Windows AD domain and I want to query AD and find the OU path or Distinguished Name of a computer for which I have the hostname.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this approach:

1. Use LDP.exe (comes with Windows) or some other LDAP tool to determine your LDAP filter.  When you've got a working LDAP filter, you're half-way there.  What are you using?
2. Then start fiddling in C# or VB.NET.  What code have you tried?  I'm a C#-er.  I can probably help but it would be quicker if I had something to start with.
3. Buy this book: [The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170).  It's worth every penny.  It now appears to be available on Kindle so you can be reading it within minutes with the Kindle app.  By the time you've finished it, you'll be answering questions on this site, instead of asking them.  :-)